# Is there such a thing as a pulse relay?

Tags: relay, pulse

Is there such a thing as a pulse relay? So that I do not have to supply constant power for it to remain open, instead just pulse it?

Comment: You mean like latching?

Comment: Yes I mean I just pulse it, or click a button and it switches on or off depending on the current state.

Comment: Are you okay with independent on and off circuits?

Comment: There are different kinds. For low current (less than 1A) they're very common. There are also types for power (even up to 100A+) used for pay-as-you-go electricity in some countries, I believe. Single coil (bipolar drive), dual coil (on and off coils) and alternating single coil (pulse on pulse off). The latter type were used in the old X10 home automation switched receptacles.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, these are called *latching relays* as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams noted in his comment.

From Wikipedia: [Relay/Latching Relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay)

> A latching relay (also called "impulse", "keep", or "stay" relays) maintains either contact position indefinitely without power applied to the coil. The advantage is that one coil consumes power only for an instant while the relay is being switched, and the relay contacts retain this setting across a power outage.